# Matrices with cryptocode package

Tags: matrices

I am using the package `cryptocode` to typeset protocols in a nice way, but I have a problem with matrices. Here is a MWE which shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cryptocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%[ht]
\begin{center}
\fbox{%
\pseudocode{%
    \textbf{Sender} \<\< \textbf{Receiver} \\[][\hline]
    \<\< \text{compute } P = \begin{pmatrix}
        A \\ B + C
    \end{pmatrix} \\
    \text{compute } Q = R+S-T \<\< \\
    \< \sendmessageright*{Q} \< \\
    \< \sendmessageleft*{P} \< \\
}
}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

and, as you can see, the matrix is not typeset correctly (the alignment is wrong). How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the command `\pseudocode` mingles with the definition of `\\` and other internals that are also relevant for `\pmatrix`. I can't offer a general solution. A quick hack is to save the matrix *outside* of `\pseudocode` in a box and to use this box inside of `\pseudocode`, like this: Before the pseudo code, add

```
\newsavebox\Pmatrix
\setbox\Pmatrix\hbox
 {$\begin{pmatrix}
    A \\ B + C
  \end{pmatrix}$%
 }
```

In the pseudo code, use `\Pmatrix` instead of the matrix:

```
\<\< \text{compute } P = \usebox\Pmatrix \\
```

Comment: Works perfectly! It may not be a general solution but it does what it should. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

As gernot explained `pseudocode` mingles with the definition of `\\`. An alternative solution to using boxes defined outside of `\pseudocode` is to use `\pclb` instead of `\\` within the matrix. This works as `\pclb` (more or less) maps to the original definition of `\\`.

So the following

```
\pseudocode{%
\textbf{Sender} \<\< \textbf{Receiver} \\[][\hline]
\<\< \text{compute } P = \begin{pmatrix}
    A \pclb B + C
\end{pmatrix} \\
\text{compute } Q = R+S-T \<\< \\
\< \sendmessageright*{Q} \< \\
\< \sendmessageleft*{P} \< \\
}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: `\tabularnewline` is better