# Cryptocode breaks multi-column matrices

Tags: matrices, cryptocode

I am using the package `cryptocode` to typeset some algorithms. There, I need to write a 2x2 matrix, but using `&` breaks the compilation with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex`.

Here is a minimal example of the code I want to write:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cryptocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{pchstack}[center]
  \procedure[mode=text, linenumbering]{Procedure name}{
    % Uncommenting this line fails
    % Set $M = \begin{pcmbox}\begin{pmatrix}A & B \\ C & D\end{pmatrix}\end{pcmbox}$ \\ 
    Set $M = \begin{pcmbox}\begin{pmatrix}A \\ C \end{pmatrix}\end{pcmbox}$
  }
\end{pchstack}
\end{document}
```

The second line is basically the example from section 3.10 of the cryptocode documentation, which recommends the use of the `pcmbox` environment to fix the low level commands. It appears to me, that this does not fix `&`, as the disabled line causes a compilation failure with errors related to missing endgroups, missing `$` and other internal problems that I can't identify.

The only somewhat related question I have found is [Matrices with cryptocode package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328745/matrices-with-cryptocode-package) - which is exactly the case that is covered in the documentation (misaligned entries in only 1 column), but does not apply here (more than 1 column).

Comment: Works if I use `{\begin{pmatrix} A & B .... \end{pmatrix}}` and thus hiding the `&`'s

Comment: @daleif Thanks, that already solves it. Would you mind writing it as an answer, so It is more visible? How exactly does adding the braces hide the `&`?